# Redirect permanent (310) occurs twice

Tags: c#, redirect

I've used RedirectPermanent in my web application mvc controller.
Checking it in redirect checkers sites shows that it occurs two times! And It'll cause problems in google search console.

My url example:

https://danito.ir/sarvbook.babol/101504-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%81%DB%8C%D9%85-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86---%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9

I've checked it here for example:
[www.redirect-checker.org](http://www.redirect-checker.org)

[image: Check result]

I'll appreciate any hint.

Comment: Great.. Nobody knows ! I'll post the answer when I've solved it.